# Most time efficient method of finding all simple paths between all nodes in an undirected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

To expand on the title, I need **all** simple (non-cyclical) paths between all nodes in a very large undirected graph.

The most obvious optimization I can think of is that once I have calculated all the paths between a particular pair of nodes I can just reverse them all instead of recalculating when I need to go the other way.

I was looking into transitive closures and the Floyd–Warshall algorithm, but it looks like the best I could do if I went down that route would be to find only the shortest paths between all nodes.

Any ideas? Right now I'm looking at running a DFS on every node in the graph, which seems to me to be significantly less than optimal.

Comment: It feels like some kind of dynamic programming is what you need here. If you find a path A->B and you've already found paths for B->C, then you filter out the ones with nodes in common and you've got your paths A->C.

Comment: The number of paths are exponential, so there are no efficient (polynomial) algorithm intrinsically.

Comment: I don't think there is any guarantee that the paths are exponential in size.  For example the ring of size N and the ring of size N+1 both have only one path.

Comment: But still probably exponential in some fashion.

Comment: What do you mean with *all* simple paths? Shortest paths or really all simple paths? If it isn't only shortest, than number of paths is exponential, e.g. for graph `K_n`, number of paths between 2 nodes is `sum i!`, `for 0<=i<n-1`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the reasoning behind your idea that DFS is significantly less than optimal. In fact, DFS is clearly optimal here.

If you traverse the graph, limiting the branching only to vertices which haven't been visited in this branch so far, then the total number of nodes in the DFS tree will be equal to the number of simple paths from the starting vertex to all other vertices. As all of these paths are a part of your output, the algorithm cannot be meaningfully improved, as you can't reduce complexity below the size of the output.

There is simply no way to output a factorial amount of data in polynomial time, regardless of what the problem is or what algorithm you are using.